# Measurement of sound

Tags: sound

I'm trying to develop what is shown in the image below:

[image]

A sound level meter where through its input I can show the RMS value on a computer screen. For now I'm just trying to do the analog front end.

This is what I have:

[image]

Starting with the microphone and pre-amplifier, I used as an input the sound of some animal farms and amplified that 5 times so the next stages of the circuit could work better with the signal. If I plan to do this in a real circuit board I need to bias the FET that is inside the microphone with a resistor and DC couple the input signal with a capacitor, I didnt do that here because there's no transistor, I simulated the microphone with just a voltage source. I'm not sure if with an actual circuit board things would go differently.

Here is the result:

[image]

Next the signal goes through an A weighting filter to emulate the perceived human ear as a function of frequency:

[image]

With this input signal at the microphone, there's an attenuation because the amplitude of the output signal of the A-filter is lower than the amplitude of the signal that entered the A-filter.

I would say this is due to the frequency of the input signal being in the zone where the A-filter makes the signal go lower (the figure in the right is the frequency response of the A-filter):

[image]

If I don't amplify the signal at the begining I would have almost a 0V signal at the end.

The next stages are the full wave rectifer and the squaring circuit. To compute the RMS, I need to first square the signal than compute an average out of that.  One problem that I had was that the squaring circuit (= multiplier circuit) isn't valid for the third quadrant, if the input is negative it won't work.

I had to make a full wave rectifier to convert the negative values of the input to positive:

[image]

The results:

[image]

Everything here goes well except there are some instances where the values for Vmulti (after multiplying the input with itself) go negative, I think the multiplier circuit is not very sensitive to low voltage values but is this best I have right now.

After that I need to do an average, so I made that according to this:

[image]

I have 3 RC circuits with different time constants. One of them requires the peak value to be measured, it just makes reading the measurement easy as it has a short time constant. The one made has a time constant of 35ms.

Here is a better view of the circuit:

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

I still need to make a square root of the output but I could do that in the microcontroller. The next stage would be an amplifier to scale the output signal in a way that I could make better use of the microcontroller resolution, it isn't done yet because I still haven't chosen a microcontroller.

One of the questions that I have is how to convert the RMS value to SPL according to this:

[image]

I have to keep in mind that I amplified the signal one time in the beginning where the feedback resistor can always change (if the signal has a very low amplitude I need to amplify more) and then one more time in the end of the AFE. The RMS value at the input may not be the 'real' one, what should I do?

There's concerns about the calibration.  I have no idea how to make it here. All I saw about this is that the pre-amplifier stage is what I should use for calibration, where I use as an input some wave where I know its SPL and keep changing the feedback resistor until in the microcontroller I get the same SPL value but that doesn't seem very pratical in my case, the biggest reason being that I have no way of guaranteeing that I can emit a SPL known input.

I tested this with a sine wave as a microphone input without the pre-amplifier and I got the a very close value for the RMS.

I also would like to hear more opinions about the things I did hear as well if possible.

Comment: You've certainly spent a while preparing this but, this is a Q&A site, not a forum, so it would help if you'd focus on a question.

Comment: The questions are in the two last paragraphs, i was just trying to make the post complete of be easier to help me

Comment: It is difficult to make an RMS circuit that has a wide dynamic range. Why not get a powerful MCU with DSP capability and do most of your processing in software.

Comment: I wanted to apply the mic + pre amplifier directly to the MCU but i was tasked not to it and make it the same way as it is in the first image i uploaded here

Comment: Is there a reason for replicating that figure? Using two ADCs for the same channel and doing RMS calculations analog when they could be trivially done in software seems bizarre to me.

Comment: You need to consider the frequency response of your microphone - it probably won't be flat in the area of interest and you'll need to compensate for that. When I used to calibrate sound level meters we used a mechanical device that was a crank and piston driven by a motor calibrated to give 400Hz at a known pressure level. This was after applying known frequencies at known levels to the electronics. It was quite labor intensive. Nowadays the average PC could automate the testing but you'd need to accurately measure the signal levels of the given soundcard.

Comment: @user1850479 Challenge the teacher made i guess, unfortunately i dont get to choose

Answer (score 5):

Unless the MCU is very slow, there's not much point in having all the analogue circuitry - not unless you're going for a vintage design. And I'm not discouraging that. It'd surely be quite an experience to design and tweak a well-performing analog signal chain like you propose.

If the MCU was a Z80 or an 8-bit AVR, then sure, you need the analog signal conditioning. But just take an RP2040 with an external ADC, and all the filtering, peak detection etc. can be done in a couple of lines of C, literally, in real time. I would just get a Raspberry Pico, hook up an external audio codec, and call it a day.

You can prototype the whole thing with Python using NumPy and an audio input library on a PC, and then easily convert the code to C or C++.