# What power supply do I need for this analog multiplier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog

[image]

It's not mentioned in the image above. If I only work in the first quadrant, is it possible to supply the op-amps with a vcc of 5 V and a vee of 0 V?

Edit: Also in the question it says if I wanted to do a square operation I can do it with a single input and R = 500 Ω. So I take from the circuit the op-amp connected to v2? I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: You need to create a virtual earth. Tie all the points that have a gnd symbol together and supply them with 2.5V. This is usually done with a voltage divider and an opamp as a unit gain buffer. Choose your opamps wisely as std devices like the lm324 will give limited output swing.

Comment: @Kartman i tried this in LTSpice with a mcp6004 and it didnt even iterate to a solution. Vcc = 5V and Vee = 0v

Comment: You need to create a virtual earth. Simple to do in a simulation.

Comment: @G0tBlackOps First off, if you take Kartman's suggestion then you also need to change the -1 V input. You can't just leave it at -1 V. Also, your v1 and v2 inputs will need to be biased, as well. And they cannot be at or below the half-supply voltage because you cannot cause the current to go backwards through the diodes just as you cannot take the logarithm of 0 or negative numbers (without an imaginary result, anyway.) And... there's a number of things to do. And do you understand how it works? And if all you have is +5 V, then you need rail to rail in/out opamps to do much of anything.

Comment: This reminds me of a 741 op amp circuit I saw published in a Fairchild Semiconductor catalog in the early 70's. For that you would use a + 15V and - 15V supplies.

Comment: @jonk Then i guess this isnt a good circuit if i only have an opamp that can take a maximum of 5V for the supply voltage. I have the solutions for this problem but it doest talk about the power supply. Is there any circuit that can do analog multiplication where i dont have to supply more that 5 v ?

Comment: @jonk I took this circuit from here: https://m.blog.naver.com/specialist0/220842813253 . If you use google translate it doest seem he worried about biasing v1 and v2

Comment: @G0tBlackOps Are we back on the topic of AM modulation and I/Q demodulation? I never can tell. If so, I think the MC1496 is still around (I've got bunches of them.) So if this is about that, you should look at it. I think the MC1495 is probably gone, these days. (Rochester may still have some.) Basically just look up the Gilbert cell (he died a few years ago, sorry to say.) Or are you really just looking to make a DC analog computer of some kind.

Comment: @jonk nothing to with the am modulation! Trying to do a sound level meter where there is a need for a square multiplier for the analog part. To do that with op amps all i found was 2 methods, one with the antilog and the one you just mentioned (gilbert cel). The max power supply for the sound level meter is 5 v

Comment: @G0tBlackOps You really need to specify all the details of what's going on with the sound level meter transducers and expected ranges for the signals that are to be multiplied and the resulting output range, etc. Lots more than you wrote, anyway.

Comment: @jonk https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/630224/measurement-of-sound here's the post about the sound level meter i made. Not sure if that square circuit does any good here, perhaps i should scrap that idea and just dont use it

Comment: @G0tBlackOps Is that an electret microphone? (Resistor to power, is why I ask.) So all of this will be in the exact details of your microphone transducer, what DC bias it possesses along with the AC riding on it, etc. This is real design work and I'd be pulling out my logbook and starting at the beginning by writing down my theoretical predictions, followed up by making actual measurements, and logging down tables of results. Etc.

Comment: @jonk I'm planbing to do with a electrostatic capacitor-bases microphone with a sensitivity of of -44dbV. i need to check the exact model cus i dont remember right now

Comment: Can you share the book name?

Comment: @Electronx I took that circuit from this blog: https://m.blog.naver.com/specialist0/220842813253 ... I dont have any details on the book, so translate that website to your language and good luck finding it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for the circuit to operate from a 5 V supply. Let's choose 3 V as the virtual ground voltage, because the output voltage of IOP5 will decrease from this value. With a sixth amplifier, we can achieve that the output voltage varies between 0 V and 3 V. Input voltages can only be positive with respect to virtual ground and cannot exceed 2 V.
The product of the input voltages should be less than 3. It requires rail-to-rail input and output amplifiers operating from 5 V, but this should not be a problem.

Let's look at three examples of multiplying inputs:

(2 x 1.5 = 3)
[image]

[image]

1.5 x 1.5 = 2.25[image]

(0.7 x 0.5 = 0.35)

Square operation requires 2 parallel inputs, one is not enough.

Comment: If the inputs were to come from a microcontroller, how would i relate them to a virtual ground?

Comment: The audio frequency signal is fed via AC coupling to a resistor voltage divider set to 4 V. The amplitude of the signal can be + - 1 V. Thus, the input signal varies between 3V and 5V. A buffer amplifier (with a gain of 1) may be required due to the low input impedance.

Comment: If the microntroller can only output a max of 5V, could i lower the virtual ground voltage? Because with 5V i cant have a resistor voltage divider set to 4 V

Comment: Reducing the voltage of the virtual ground reduces the maximum output signal, so the maximum product is reduced from 3 to less.

Comment: Whats happens if i put another another amplifier?

Comment: The limiting factor is not the last amplifier, but the IOP 5 op amp. Its output in the original construction only went negative (+ - supply voltages). Now that output is can vary between virtual ground and 0 V. This limits the maximum product. It would simplify everything a lot if we turned the + 5 V into - 5 V with a switching regulator, so we would have a negative power supply as well. From then on, the virtual ground is unnecessary, the inputs could be between 0 and 5 V, the output as well. A low-power inverting stabilizer is not too complicated.

Comment: There is a circuit that does this +5 -> -5V ... ICL7660 if I remember well. Replaced by https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl7660.pdf?ts=1667744396484&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTL7660%253Futm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_campaign%253Dti-null-null-xref-cpc-pf-google-wwe%2526utm_content%253Dxref%2526ds_k%253D%257B_dssearchterm%257D%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526gclid%253DEAIaIQobChMIq7ik_d-Z-wIVZ49oCR1RMAY2EAAYASAAEgLAWfD_BwE%2526gclsrc%253Daw.ds

Answer (score 1):

> Last question: you tried ... but did not had success, so did not work ...

Your circuit is a old one as me, and it was 'designed' with old op-amp which needed +15V & -15V.

The simple circuits you used are "theoritical" circuit. It should work with ideal components, but in the real world, some adjustments must be done. The components have "many" defaults that must be "corrected" ( temperature dependance, dispersion of characteristics are some ...)

NB: logarithmic (and antilog, use of a log circuit within a feedback loop) are "difficult" to set up, but possible.
Setup has been made with "interactive" capabilities of [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm).

Example of a circuit. Diodes (and resistors ...) should be kept at a "constant" temperature.
Here is a simulation of "log" circuit (5 decades, not too bad for an old one ...) that is quasi "perfect" (use op-amp with xFET inputs with some offsets - can be simplified with 10/20 turn trimmers).
LF13741 is "old" but can be easily replaced.

Tests are made with input ranging from 100 uV to 10 V (log stepping x10).

[image]

And here, to show the behavior of temperature (0°, 25, 50, 75 °C). Curve 25 °C in grey.
One can see how temperature has a very bad influence.
Circuit should then work at stabilized 50 -> 75 °C or more (125 °C).

[image]

And if you are interested in "analog" circuit, constant temperature needed,
this one works for 7 decades (modified for extended range).

[image]

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Have you read the last question of the OP? Ok, I forgot to comment.

Comment: This has be done. Convinced ???

Comment: You've given an example of a log circuit when the question is about multiplying & squaring. I don't see the (direct) relevance.

Comment: If the fundamental circuit does not work ... how could you use the "idea" with log & antilog circuits about multiplying and squaring? You can apply the idea only if you have "trustful" circuits working. That is what I say.